# How i can add datepicker and timepicker inside jtable of column Item Date,From Time And To Time?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

How i can add `datepicker` and `timepicker` inside `jtable` of column Item Date,From Time And To Time?

I already added `combobox` in `jtable`.

[Screen Shot is added of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR1b4.png)
[image]

Comment: post the code here instead of linking it to a 3rd party host

Comment: I'd recommend starting with [JTable Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [JTable Using Other Editors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) and just about any other tutorial about custom editors in `JTable`

Comment: most probably i would say you add them the same way you added the combobox

Comment: Am not able to post my source code that's why i use 3rd party.Am new to this don't know how to post code properly. while posting they are saying give details more about code. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: i tried but its not working. @XtremeBaumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableColumn dateColumn = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
dateColumn.setCellEditor(new TimeTableEditor());
TableColumn dateColumn1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
dateColumn1.setCellEditor(new TimeTableEditor());
TableColumn dateColumn3 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
dateColumn3.setCellEditor(new DateTableEditor());
```

Am using **LGoodDatePicker-GitHub** https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker and put the above code in PropertyChange of JTable.**(0,4,5)is the column index**.